# How to change Iframe height based on its content when Iframe content is on different domain?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an Iframe with a content loaded from different domain:

```
<div class="iframe">
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var queryString = unescape(document.location.search.split('?id=').join(''));
      document.write("<iframe id=\"frame\" onload=\"resize()\" src=\"http://differentdomain.com/" + queryString + "\" scrolling=\"no\" width=\"850\" height=\"450\" frameborder=0></iframe>");
   </script>
</div>
```

The content of an Iframe can be of different height.

I have a method `resize()` executing when iframe loads as follows:

```
function resize() {
    var iFrameID = document.getElementById("frame");
    if (iFrameID) {
        iFrameID.height = "";
        iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

When running the page I have an access denied error, I'm assuming because of cross-domain issues.

How can I fix that, so my frame's heights will be changed dynamically based on its content?

Thank's

Comment: If you [can control the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy), if you can't, there's nothing you can do due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
Except if you also control the other domain, then you can disable the protection.